# Picking using forearms vs Picking using wrist for palm muting

Tags: guitar, health, picking, palm-muting

I have been playing for around 3 years and am mostly self taught.

I have seen many people recommend the use of your forearms for picking instead of using your wrist as this might lead to Carpel Tunnel syndrome.

I have started incorporating this method of playing but I find it very difficult to palm mute the strings when I pick by turning my forearms.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Ask the people who told you that where they heard about it. That's not even good advice. Let the master speak https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zY85LH4yvo4 and do some picking demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlePTeNihp4

Comment: Related: [What's the correct technique for strumming a guitar?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7023/whats-the-correct-technique-for-strumming-a-guitar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is completely unavoidable to palm mute and play by moving only the forearm. Besides I would argue that it is not a good idea to play entirely by moving the forearm anyway. A better idea would be to combine movement of the forearm, wrist and flexing the pick between your forefinger and thumb - it is hard to teach this over the internet, consider getting a teacher.